# Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

edit-category-component.html:

```
<app-form-category *ngIf="model" [model]="model"
(onSaveChanges)="saveChanges($event)"></app-form-category>

<mat-spinner *ngIf="!model"></mat-spinner>
```

edit-category.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { categoryCreationDTO, categoryDTO } from 'src/app/models/category';
import { CategoriesService } from 'src/app/services/categories.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-category',
  templateUrl: './edit-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-category.component.scss']
})
export class EditCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  model!: categoryDTO;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.categoriesService.getById(params.id).subscribe(category =>{
        this.model = category;
      })
    });
  }

  saveChanges(categoryCreationDTO: categoryCreationDTO) {
    this.categoriesService.edit(this.model.id, categoryCreationDTO)
    .subscribe(()=>{
      this.router.navigate(["/magazine"])
    })
  }
}
```

category.ts

```
export interface categoryCreationDTO{
  name: string;
}

export interface categoryDTO{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

ERROR

> Error:
> src/app/components/magazine/category/edit-category/edit-category.component.html:2:30
>
> - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event'  is not assignable to parameter of type 'categoryCreationDTO'.   Property 'name' is missing
>   in type 'Event' but required in type 'categoryCreationDTO'.
>
> (onSaveChanges)="saveChanges($event)">
> ~~~~~~
>
> src/app/components/magazine/category/edit-category/edit-category.component.ts:8:16
> templateUrl: './edit-category.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component EditCategoryComponent.

I don't understand this error, could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`saveChanges` method expects object with a type of `categoryCreationDto` which in itself expects to have `name` property (as you have defined on the interface from which the argument inherits). As you are passing `$event` to an `saveChanges($event)` it doesn't have `name` on the event property. If you don't know what type of object is `event` you can `console.log()` it and after pass down to the method correctly.

I see that you try to use `eventEmitter` from a child via `OnSaveChanges` property -> Check out what is sent from the children component to the parent and use it in `saveChanges` accordingly. The `$event` object will be exactly that which you output from the children `app-form-category` via `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript expects the event response as the type you specified, but in reality, it would type `Event`.

You might want to try what is coming from the event and then assign the needed things into the api call.